# Inner Join: Is this an optimal solution?

Tags: sql, inner-join

T1: employee [id, salary]

T2: department [name, employeeid]
(employeeid is a foreign key to T1's id)

Problem: Write a query to fetch the name of the department which receives the maximum salary.

My Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM department AS a
INNER JOIN employee AS b ON a.employeeid = b.id
AND b.salary
IN (    
    SELECT max( salary )
    FROM employee AS c
)
```

Edit: The problem statement is accurate, and we're not trying to find out the employee who has the highest salary. It says "....Department which receives.....", not "...employee who receives....".

Is this ok? Or can this be optimized?

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: Are you supposed to find a department in which the employee with max salary works in, or the department whose members have max sum of salaries? Because, your code says one, and your text the other one.

Comment: And, is this a homework?

Comment: @Goran - My problem statement and code are both in agreement. It's your comment which is ambiguous. And no, it's not homework. My company doesn't assign homework. It's leisurely self exploration, looking to brush up my SQL skills a bit.

Comment: @JavaMental: Well, then your SQL is simply wrong :)

Comment: Your table definition doesn't match with your query. In your query you write `a.employeeid` but there is no column `employeeid` in either table according to the table definition at the start of your question.

Comment: @goran, @mark, My bad! corrected the column name in department.

Comment: I don't understand why one employee could work in many departments? With this database schema you could get many department names with max salary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GROUP BY the name of the department and order by SUM(salary).

```
SELECT department.name
FROM department
JOIN employee ON department.employeeid = employee.id
GROUP BY department.name
ORDER BY SUM(salary) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No, the question meant what you initially interpreted: A department has multiple employees. So we're trying to find out which Department has the highest amount of cash flowing in into it, i.e., if you sum all the salaries of all the employees in EACH department, then which Department has the highest salary?

Comment: Nice, great insight on this one too!

Comment: This query should return a list of departments with a sum of salaries of employees **in that** department. With the order by and limit clauses it will return only the department with the highest total salary, which looks to me as the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.salary, department.name
FROM department, employee 
where 
employee.id = department.employeeid and
employee.salary = (select max(salary) from employee)
```

Comment: This will definitely run faster.

Comment: Please see the table structure. With all due respect to your effort, the query doesn't fit it yet (column names).